# Laravel - How to set up index resource to include the inverse one-to-many model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have two models, one for Company and one for Invoice. There is a one-to-many relationship as the company can have many invoices.

I am now setting up the index page for the invoices, but in the index page, I want to display the company name. How can I set up the controller if I don't yet have the ID for the company?

This is what I have so far on my invoice controller

```
public function index()
    {
        
        return Inertia::render('Invoices/Index', [
            'invoices' => Invoice::all(),
        ]);

    }
```

That passes all the invoices to the correct route, but I don't know how to pass the company data.

My Invoice model looks like this - and the table has a company_id field

```
public function company(){

     return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);

}
```

and my Company model looks like this

```
public function invoices(){

    return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class);

}
```

The company migration is this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('website')->nullable();
            $table->string('address_1')->nullable();
            $table->string('address_2')->nullable();
            $table->string('city')->nullable();
            $table->string('post_code')->nullable();
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and the invoice migration is this

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->from(8023052);
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('invoice_company_id');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->decimal('subtotal', 8, 2);
            $table->decimal('tax', 8, 2);
            $table->decimal('total', 8, 2);
            $table->date('invoice_date');
            $table->date('due_date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: have you read the eloquent documentation for relationships? ... how to setup them up, how to query them, how to return results, how dynamic properties work, eager loading, etc etc ?  you should provide your model definitions so we can see the relationships you have defined

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. and I can easily pull through the correct company using find($id) on individual invoice pages. but in the index resource, I don't know how to pass the ID if I don't have it in the controller. - @lagbox please see my updated post

Comment: how to pass the ID for what? you are just retrieving all your invoices ... what ID do you need? each invoice has the ID of the company it belongs to in its fields ... and the company is accessible via the relationship `company`

Comment: hi, can you show your migration for these two ?

Comment: hi @lagbox the id for the company. I am passing all invoices as a prop to my react app route from my controller. But that does not include any company data it only has the company ID. I can of course pass all companies as a prop as well, and then match them on the front end but then doesn't that defeat the object of using a reverse relationship?

Comment: Hi @BlackLotus, not a problem. I have updated my post to include the migrations.

Comment: you should eager load the relationship

Comment: @threelyons0405 as lagbox said, you should eager load the relationship. And I suggest you to add foreign key for `company_id` in `invoices` table

Comment: Hi @lagbox that's done the trick. I did read through that but didn't really understand how to use it till now. many hansk

Comment: no worries, you were not afraid to try something new and you got your answer, that is a good step `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to LagBox and BlackLotus. I figured out how to do it. And in the end, my controller method looks like this now and it works perfectly.

```
public function index()
    {

        $invoices = Invoice::with('company')->get();

        return Inertia::render('Invoices/Index', [
            'invoices' => $invoices,
        ]);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading),

```php
public function index()
{
    
    return Inertia::render('Invoices/Index', [
        'invoices' => Invoice::with(['company'])->all(),
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks but that resulted in the following error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()". but I have figured it out anyway by reading more about Eager Loading. but many thanks for your help

Comment: btw, you would need to call `get` on the Builder as `all` is a Model method